# I can not see all items on my prototype cell.It seems like default cell but it is not

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, storyboard

I want to make some blog or forum app.I made a home page to see other users's posts.I used tableview and prototype cell to do that.But when i run my app, i can not see all my items in my prototype cell.And they seem like default cells but they are not.I debugged it with changing cell's background color.I can see it but not completely true.

Here is my Home Page View Controller

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class FeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
   
    var postDizisi = [Post]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        verileriAl()

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postDizisi.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "protCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedTableViewCell
        cell.textView.text = postDizisi[indexPath.row].content
        cell.usernameLabel.text = postDizisi[indexPath.row].username
        return cell
    }
    
    @objc func verileriAl() {
        print("done")
        let query = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.createAlert(title: "HATA", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "HATA")
            }else {
                if objects!.count > 0 {
                    self.postDizisi.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    
                    for object in objects! {
                        if let username = object.object(forKey: "username") as?  String {
                            if let userContent = object.object(forKey: "content") as? String {
                                    let post = Post(username: username, content: userContent)
                                    self.postDizisi.append(post)
                                
                            }
                        }else {
                            print("hata aldık")
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func createAlert(title : String , message : String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        let okBut
ton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        present(alert, animated: true)
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(verileriAl), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "veriGirildi"), object: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is my upload View Controller

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class UploadViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var shareButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var postTextView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        usernameLabel.text = PFUser.current()?.username
        
        
    }

    @IBAction func shareButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let post = PFObject(className: "Post")
        if PFUser.current() != nil {
            post["username"] = PFUser.current()?.username
            post["content"] = postTextView.text
            
            post.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "HAT", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "HATA", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                    let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
                    alert.addAction(okButton)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true)
                }else {
                    self.postTextView.text = ""
                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
                    
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "veriGirildi"), object: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I want to see like this

[image]

But when i runned my app it seems like this

[image]

Atil and ibrahimmbyrrm is just usernameLabel contents.Why it doesn't display other items on prototype cell

I want to see other users's posts on Home Page but my cell doesn't work successfully.I need help to fix it.I have this problem at all my projects.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same question you deleted, after you said it was fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately yes :(

Comment: OK - then, as I said in my comments yesterday, show us your Cell layout, including all of the constraints.

Comment: i added the screenshot.I hope i added true pictrue what you wanted

Comment: Well, you made the Document Outline pane to narrow to actually **see** your constraints. Did you give the textView leading and trailing constraints? Did you give it a Height constraint? If you want it to auto-size its height, did you disable scrolling? Please review [ask] ... it is very difficult to answer questions when only bits of information are given.